# Compute $v,W,k$ such that the following is true

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

$$
\left\{ x \in \mathbb{Z}^4 | 
\begin{pmatrix} 
5 & 3 & 7 & 0 \\
2 & -4 & 6 & 5
\end{pmatrix} 
x =
\begin{pmatrix} 
5 \\0
\end{pmatrix} 
\right\} = \left\{ v + Wy \ | \ y \in \mathbb{Z}^k \right\}
$$

I denoted $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^T$ and tried expressing $x_1$ and $x_2$ in terms of $x_3$ and $x_4$ but i could not proceed. I am studying for linear programming (optimization) exam and i found this exercise. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Hints (if I guessed correctly your notation and *part* of your problem):

$$\begin{pmatrix}5&3&7&0\\
2&\!\!-4&6&5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{pmatrix}=\binom 50\iff\begin{cases}5x_1+3x_2+7x_3=5\\{}\\2x_1-4x_2+6x_3+5x_4=0\end{cases}$$

Two particular solutions to this system are

$$\begin{pmatrix}\;15\\\;\;0\\\!\!-10\\\;\;6\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}\;\;0\\\!\!-10\\\;\;5\\\!\!-14\end{pmatrix}$$

Now I'd need to know what  $\,v,y,W\,$ are expected to be and whether you insist all is done over a ring that *is not* a field (this makes things very hard!) . Also, is it $\,k=4\,$ in the rightmost set?

Comment: this is an exercise from the exam stated exactly the same. Suppose everything you like. They probably want a solution. I don't get it. I will skip. Thanks for your time